# GitLab project cloning stalls after 'remote: Enumerating objects' when cloning on same network

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04, git-clone

My company has a VPN to access self-hosted GitLab. I can clone a project on my laptop. When I clone the project on the same network as Gitlab, it stocks after 'remote: Enumerating objects'. How can I fix it? The Host is on the Ubuntu 16. Git is updated. Aside from HTTP and SSH, I also tried a number of values for `http.postBuffer` and `core.compression` and In Gitlab repository pages, the IP address in clone boxes is different from the server IP address.

```
Cloning into '***'...
Server supports multi_ack_detailed
Server supports side-band-64k
Server supports allow-tip-sha1-in-want
Server supports allow-reachable-sha1-in-want
Server supports ofs-delta
Server version is git/2.35.1.gl1
want 59bf199c767d213cedc7b95d4902fc15c6a04ff6 (HEAD)
want 59bf199c767d213cedc7b95d4902fc15c6a04ff6 (refs/heads/main)
done

stock....
```

Clone a project from selft hosted Gitlab server in a private network